# calculation of adsr from envelope

Tags: audio, manufacturing

In audio synthesis, we have ADSR envelope;

[image]

Now, let us say I wanted to *detect* A,D,S and R given a signal. We can determine the beginning and end of relevant signal with a simple gate, and find the envelope with an envelope follower. My proposed solution for detecting everything else is look for critical points (first/second derivative test) of the envelope.

Is this a possible/the best solution? What is a ballpark price estimate for 10 units of an IC that will do this? 100 units?

Many thanks in advance

Joe

Comment: If I had known you were going to accept a answer within 25 minutes I wouldn't have bothered writing a detail response.

Comment: Sorry, your comments are definitely extremely interesting. I will be more patient next time. I have to do some math homework now, but I will study your comments in detail later - PS what do you use to draw circuits

Comment: I use Eagle for schematics and boards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the signal through an envelope detector, and differentiate the envelope, either electronically, or in software. The four periods should show as a positive level (Attack), a negative (Decay), (near) zero (Sustain), and again negative (Release).

Telling how much a solution will cost is not possible unless you tell us what you want to do with the result. Do you want to log the 4 time values? Display them? In those cases you'll need a microcontroller anyway, and then you can do the differentiation in software, that would save you a few cents. The envelope detector is a (precision) diode, a capacitor, and a resistor.
AFAIK that's the most application-specific you can go for these low quantities. The microcontroller will cost you anything between a few tens of cents and a few dollar. If you need a display the sky is the limit.

**edit**
Since you only want to log the data connect an EEPROM to the microcontroller (maybe it has storage available on-chip) and provide a serial interface to a PC.

Comment: I was aware of envelope followers, and have updated my answer to reflect this. Would still love to hear how much you think an ic would cost.

Comment: No, a display is unnecessary, so is logging. I will just need to output a certain format. Many thanks for the great news. Joe

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking for is a *amplitude detector*, or often just called a *detector*.  What you want is no different than what goes on in a AM radio, except that your frequencies are all lower.

The basic AM detector circuit is:

[image]

The cap charges up to the peak of the input waveform every positive peak, but it decays down more slowly according to the R-C time constant.  The time constant is long enough to minimize the decay between individual carrier cycles, but short enough to track the highest modulation frequency of interest.

That's in theory, in practise real detectors are a bit more fancy:

[image]

The transistor acts like the diode, but provides more output current than what is drawn from the input signal.  The overall circuit now has a higher input impedance relative to its output impedance.  The addition of R2 and C2 low pass filter the raw detector result a bit.  There will be some component at the carrier frequency on C1 and R1 as it gets bumped up to the level of the peak each cycle.  This filter is usually set to roll off at the highest modulation frequency of interest.  R2 is generally about 10x R1 so as to not intefere with the R1-C1 time constant.

For example, let's say we're detecting a AM radio station at 1 MHz.  R2 and C2 can be set to roll off at 10 kHz since there is no AM radio content above that.  That is still 100 times lower than the carrier frequency, so the little bit of 1 MHz signal on C1 will get attenuated by 100 while the audio signal is attenuated only 3 dB at 10 kHz and less at lower frequencies.

In your case you want to detect the amplitude of audio signals, so all frequencies are lower but the principle is the same.  You can make a detector circuit like the one shown, then feed the result into a A/D of a microcontroller and do whatever processing you think is appropriate for detecting the four phases you believe your audio signal will have.  Keep in mind that audio signals haven't read your description and won't usually have such nice clean four sections as your diagram.

Comment: Re behavior of audio signals, this is why I was thinking in terms of differentiation. This would allow users to set tolerances to taste, ie a=dv/dt>x, d=dv/dt<x, etc

Answer (score 2):

Detecting the ADSR in any non-laboratory setting will be difficult.  ADSR is an oversimplification used in synthesizing sounds.  The real world is never quite so simple. The Sustain phase, for example, is rarely flat.  The attack could have multiple peaks.  There might be some vibrato in the release.  As if that wasn't bad enough, any reverb picked up by a mic will also confuse things, also causing multiple peaks in the attack and other effects.

Even so, detecting the ADSR could be possible in the right circumstances.  We don't really know if you have the right circumstances since you didn't give enough information in your question.

As for cost...  It all depends.  If you have something very simple, and it doesn't need to be super fast or handle lots of audio channels at the same time, then there are many cheap DSP's and even some 32-bit Microcontrollers that can do this.  In low volume (<100) then you're probably talking about US$5 per chip.  Higher volumes (>10,000) might bring that down to US$3/chip.

Beyond the very simple case it becomes really difficult to say anything.  For example, if you are trying to detect each individual note in a polyphonic recording then you're basically hosed.  It's possible, maybe, but super difficult and worthy of a Ph.D. if you're successful.  The hardware to do this would be super fast and expensive.  But I can't say how expensive.